# I´m trying to geting total price*quantity.input from different items and products. How to console just the changed array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help: 
My function to calculate the price*quantity.input is working well but just changes the total (id="1") from the first item.
What should I change in my code to get the total in every item that I change the input of?
If I change (input) from item number 3 and console.log I get [0.89, 1, 4] an array with each item and the total in "id:"1" is not changed,
and if I change the first item the total in "id="1" is changed.

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false-->

<!-- language: lang-js -->
<script>
         $('.quantity').on('change', getTotals);
           function getTotals() {
           var totals = $('.quantity').map(function() {
           var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
           return parseFloat($tr.find('.priceCell').text()) *                     parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
            }).get();
           console.log(totals)
           document.getElementById('1').innerText = '€' +                           parseFloat(totals).toFixed(2)  
             }
</script>

<!-- language: lang-html -->
<% items.roupa.forEach(function(item){ %>
  <div class="T-shirts selectt">
    div class="shop-item" data-item-id= "<%= item.id %>" >
    <img class="shop-item-image" src="/resources/images/tshirt/<%= item.imgName %>">
     <div class="shop-item-details">
      <table>
       <span class="shop-item-title"><%= item.name %></span>
        <table>
         <tr>
          <td class="priceCell"><%= item.price / 100 %> </td>
          <td><input type="number" class="form-control3 text-center quantity" min="1" max="999" value="1"></td>
         </tr>
        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" class="buttonadd" type="button">To Cart </button>
       <span class="shop-item-price1" id="1"><%= item.price2 / 100 + '€' %></span>
      </table>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  <% }) %>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with `id="1"`. `id` values must be **unique** per-document. Any specific reason you're working with `id` rather than `class`?

Comment: I tried before with class too, but don't work neither, I was just trying all the options